# Tracking the next badge shows empty box

Tags: bug, status-review, badges, badge-progress

As a new user, I took the tour, and was granted the `Informed` badge. Yay!

> [image]

However, clicking "Track the next one" yielded an empty box, regardless of which option I clicked on (I didn't try a search).

> [image]

I've since clicked "Let us pick" and you picked `Supporter` so I guess that's my next badge I'll try for. But it was confusing to be shown an empty box.

Now that I'm no longer prompted to track the next one, is there a way to determine why that list was empty? An easy way to reproduce the issue? Any way to prevent the next new user from encountering the same?

Comment: It is pretty strange you have an empty dialog because the whole dialog html markup comes from the server when I try that dialog. Definitely something server side went belly up.

Comment: Those are tag badges you're looking at, and it makes sense that none show if you haven't made any progress towards achieving them.

Comment: @Joundill But... how would a new user know that? The button just says "Track the next one" it doesn't say "Track the next tag badge only, and by the way the dialog will be empty for you because reasons"

Comment: I agree, it's a bad design

Comment: Cross site duplicate of [this reported bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377181/track-the-next-one-window-shows-tag-badges-instead-of-normal-badges)